# Is it possible to send strings over an ethernet port connection without establishing a server/client connection?

Tags: sockets, tcp, raspberry-pi2, pyserial

I have set up a raspberry pi to redirect from ethernet to UART.  I want to send a single character from a C# application on a PC to the ethernet port on the RPi, have it sent to the UART connection.  Then there is a module on the UART connection configured to respond to certain characters.

Do I need to create a server socket program and client socket program to achieve this?

I am using the following for the redirect: https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/examples.html#tcp-ip-serial-bridge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python script you are linking is forwarding raw data from your ethernet port to the serial interface. It acts as a server listening the configured port on TCP/IP.

All you need on your PC is a TCP client.
As a starter, you could test this with telnet

e.g. `telnet <raspberry ip> <configured port>`

When the connection is established, you should be able to type in your characters.

`telnet> A`

Y